# Displacement on an acceleration versus time graph

Tags: kinematics

How do you demonstrate maximum displacement on an acceleration vs. time graph?

Answer (score 1):

Maximum displacement occurs when speed reaches zero. Speed is the area under the $a$ vs. $t$ graph, so look for the point where the area over the *x*-axis equals the area under the *x*-axis.

[image: fig]